# How to dinamically add new key/value to all nested object inside other object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have an object

```
var testArray = [name1:{xaxis:'xaxis1', yaxis:'yaxis1'}, 
                 name2:{xaxis:'xaxis2', yaxis:'yaxis2'}];
```

I have to add a new key / value paar, so it looks like this:

```
var myResult= [name1:{xaxis:'xaxis1', yaxis:'yaxis1', a:'b'}, 
                 name2:{xaxis:'xaxis2', yaxis:'yaxis2', a:'b'}];
```

I have tried:

```
testArray.map(function(e){
     e.a= b;
});
```

But it returns nothing

I have also tried this:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(testArray ).map((k, v) => k, v.map(('a') => 'b')));
```

But then I get an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

Comment: Never seen an array with key / value pairs (`[key: value]`)

Comment: Per @expressjs123's comment – did you mean `testArray` to be an array or an object? Because right now it isn't valid javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` method and loop through each object. Then, you can add the key values.

```js
var testArray = {"name1" :{xaxis:'xaxis1', yaxis:'yaxis1'}, "name2":{xaxis:'xaxis2', yaxis:'yaxis2'}};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(testArray)) {
 testArray[key].a = "b"
}

console.log(testArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var testArray = {};
testArray["name1"] = {xaxis:'xaxis1', yaxis:'yaxis1'};
testArray["name2"] = {xaxis:'xaxis2', yaxis:'yaxis2'};
```

Now

```
Object.assign(testArray["name1"], {a:'b'});
Object.assign(testArray["name2"], {a:'b'});
```

Or

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(testArray)) {
    Object.assign(testArray[key], {a:'b'});
}
```

Comment: the thing is I need to assign it dinamically. Assign one by one could not be applied

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can try something like this.